# Terraform - Resource not found for variable despite having it declared in the same file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops-services, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

Terraform can't find a resource which is declared in the same file where the reference is.

It seems that this line is causing trouble: `role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline.arn}"`. It can't find `newsapi_lambda_codepipeline` which is declared as `resource "aws_iam_role" "newsapi_lambda_codepipeline" { ... }`.

This is my main.tf:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "newsapi_lambda_builds" {
  bucket = "newsapi-lambda-builds"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "newsapi_lambda_codebuild" {
  name = "newsapi-lambda-codebuild"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newsapi_lambda_builds",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::newsapi_lambda_builds"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "lambda:invokefunction",
        "lambda:listfunctions"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "newsapi_lambda_codepipeline" {
  name = "newsapi-lambda-codepipeline"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
      ],
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.newsapi_lambda_builds.arn}",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.newsapi_lambda_builds.arn}/*"
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::newsapi_lambda_builds"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
        "codebuild:StartBuild"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_codepipeline" "newsapi_lambda" {
  name     = "newsapi-lambda"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline.arn}"

  artifact_store {
    location = "${aws_s3_bucket.newsapi_lambda_builds.bucket}"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "ThirdParty"
      provider         = "GitHub"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["newsapi_lambda"]

      configuration {
        Owner      = "Defozo"
        Repo       = "traceitfor.me_newsapi_lambda"
        Branch     = "master"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name            = "Build"
      category        = "Build"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts = ["newsapi_lambda"]
      version         = "1"
      role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codebuild.arn}"

      configuration {
        ProjectName = "newsapi-lambda"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After executing `terraform apply` I get:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_codepipeline.newsapi_lambda: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_codepipeline.newsapi_lambda: Resource 'aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline' not found for variable 'aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline.arn'
```

I don't understand why that happens. I have `aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline` declared, haven't I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your role declaration could be slightly wrong. And terraform was not able to generate an arn for that, therefore not found.

It looks like you also need to create `resource "aws_iam_role_policy"`. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline.html
It's a bit unclear why you'd need to split.

If this is not the case, let me know and I'll try to run the code myself to test.

Comment: I executed `terraform destroy` and then again `terraform apply` which revealed true errors. I corrected my mistakes and applied it again successfully. Although I don't understand why I had to destroy the infrastructure and then again apply it in order to see the errors. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: It would be good to add the errors that appeared for you here so other people can see ;)

Comment: I ran into the same situation. Running "export TF_LOG=DEBUG" allowed me to see why the resource (in this can an ECS task definition) wasn't created.

Comment: I had the same error with a aws_ecs_task_definition resource which an error in the container definition json. As soon as I removed the resource which referenced the aws_ecs_task_definition resource, I got the "real" error (Error decoding JSON). As long as some other resource references the resource with the error there is just the misleading "resource not found" error.

Answer (score 10):

For those experiencing an issue with `aws_ecs_task_definition` not finding a variable for the `aws_ecs_task_definition.XXX.arn`, there's a good chance your JSON came out malformed. Here's what I did to remedy my issue

- Replace your line with `task_definition = "[]"`
- Run `terraform plan`

At this point you should get an error. For example, I got

> module.tf.aws_ecs_task_definition.sandbox: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ContainerDefinition.MemoryReservation of type int64

In this case, I had quoted `memSize` in my `template_file` and it didn't implicitly convert to int64, hence an error.

I changed `"memoryReservation": "${mem_size}"` to `"memoryReservation": ${mem_size}`, removed the task_definition placeholder, and everything went smoothly.

Comment: Thanks! Did you figure out how to get meaningful messages in the first place? Is this a terraform bug?

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase, "an issue with `aws_ecs_task_definition` not finding a variable? 

I am working on a project where I get a similar error to OP on a file named. Is `aws_ecs_task_definition` an official term or are you using that as a catch-all placeholder for different potential problems?

Comment: this is specifically a developer error in a template file that is passed as the container definition to https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html , where the error is masked by default

Comment: They key here is the thing that's not found is the thing that's not working. In the case supplied, the resource with a problem can be 'debugged' by doing a targeted apply. Eg. `terraform apply aws_codepipeline.newsapi_lambda.aws_iam_role.newsapi_lambda_codepipeline`

Answer (score 3):

To help out with investigating such issues, you can run targeted `terraform plan`.
In my case (misconfigured reference to CIDR block from custom AWS VPC module), after running

```
terraform plan --target aws_security_group.something-or-other
```

Terraform actually provided clear error message on what exactly i did wrong this time. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me find the issue with aws_ecs_task_definition

Answer (score 0):

Since the title of the problem is pretty generic, I landed on this link.

I was able to find the problem, given the fact that there is `something wrong with the resource which was not found and hence it is not getting created`

In my case it was a variable not getting referenced correctly in `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` "event_pattern" key

```
    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": [
        "STOPPED"
    ],
    "desiredStatus": [
        "RUNNING"
    ],
    "clusterArn": [
      ${aws_ecs_cluster.main.arn}
    ]
  }
}
PATTERN
```